# Converse of the British Flag Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Exist a theorem known as [British Flag Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem). It say that in a rectangle $ABCD$ we have $PA^2 - PB^2 + PC^2 - PD^2 = 0$, for any point $P$ in the plane.

I was thinking in a type of converse of this theorem. Given a polygon with vertices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$, consider the function

$$f(P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i} {PA_i}^2, $$

where $P$ is a point in the plane. So I conjectured that

> If a polygon with vertices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ is such that $f(P) = 0$, for all point $P$ in the plane, then this polygon is a rectangle.

I can to prove easily that if $n = 4$, then this is true. Somebody know this problem? This conjecture is true? If this question is easy, but requires a expert argument, can to give me a hint of how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this polygon is a rectangle". For example, with $n=8$, we can easily create a polygon that satisfies your conditions, by taking the union of any 2 rectangles.

Comment: Well, I assume implicitly that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$  are all distinct. So, how will this union of two rectangles? Remember that a polygon is a closed curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use linear algebra to get a necessary and sufficient condition for your $f$ to be zero.

Write points in the plane as vectors. Then the hypothesis is that $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i ||P-A_i||^2 = 0$$ for all $P$. You can expand this into
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i\langle P-A_i, P-A_i \rangle = 0$$
or
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i)||P||^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i ||A_i||^2 -2\langle P , \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i A_i \rangle = 0.$$
If this is true for $P$, it must also be true for $kP$ for any scalar $k$. So for a fixed $P$ you have a polynomial of degree $2$ in $k$, which must vanish identically. It follows that a necessary and sufficient condition to have $f(P)$ identically zero is

1. $n$ is even.
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i ||A_i||^2 =0.$
3. $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i A_i = 0.$

You can find many polygons satisfying these. For example, let all the $A_i$ have equal length and let $n$ be even. Then you just need $A_1-A_2 + \cdots - A_{n-1} + A_n =0$.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed solve the question!

Comment: Just only think, that I left to pass unnoticed: "If this is true for $P$, it must also be true for $kP$ for any scalar $k$." Why?

Comment: Sorry, that statement is not right. It should say, if this is true *for all $P$* (as we are claiming), and we fix a $P$, then it must also be true for $kP$ for every $k$. That's just because we are claiming that it's true for every $P$, and then looking at the multiples of a particular $P$.

Comment: All right! I got it. But I don't understand how the big equation above together with this fact about the polynomial in $k$ implies in the three conditions.

Comment: If $ak^2 + bk =c = 0$ for all $k$ then $a=b=c=0$. From the coefficient of $k^2$ we get $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i =0$ which is the same as saying $n$ is even. From the constant term being zero, we get the second condition. From the coefficient of $k$ being zero, we get that the inner product of $P$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i A_i$ is zero. But since this is now true for any $P$, we must have $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i A_i=0$ as zero is the only vector which is orthogonal to everything.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Thanks for your patience! I will to sleep. Good night!

Comment: No problem, I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the points

$A_1 = (a,b), A_2 = (a,d) A_3 = (w,x), A_4 = (y,x), A_5 = (c,d), A_6 = (c,b), A_7 = (y,z), A_8 = (w,z) $

This satisfies your conditions, since the vertices are the union of vertices of 2 rectangles.

Proof:

> We know that $PA_1^2 - PA_2^2 + PA_5^2 - PA_6^2 = 0$ and $PA_3^2 - PA_4^2 + PA_7^2 - PA_8^2 = 0$. Add up both equations.

It is clearly not a rectangle. Note that this polygon can be self-intersecting.

You can easily set conditions on $a, b, c, d, w, x, y, z$ to find a convex polygon. A simple example would be the regular octagon.

Comment: Sorry, but not yet I can to see this polygon. I think that you are drawn two rectangles disconnected. A polygon is a connect curve.

Comment: Just to be more clear, if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are the vertices of a polygon, then $A_1A_2,A_2A_3,\ldots,A_{n-1}A_n,A_nA_1$ are the edges of this polygon.

Comment: @Walner The exact edges of the polygon doesn't matter. Do you see why this polygon satisfies your condition?

Comment: No. Do you can to draw to me? I don't know if here is allowed to put a figure, but if not, do you can to send for me? My email is walner@alu.ufc.br  Thanks!

Comment: @Walner I added a proof of the statement. This is what I meant by "union of 2 rectangles".

Comment: I think that I see what you has in mind. But this can't to occur. Remember that I say in the comment above about how is the edge of a polygon. Indeed, if you consider your polygon, you have that $f(P) = 0$. But your polygon isn't a polygon indeed. See that $A_2A_3$ isn't a edge. The exact edges does matter, because this allowed that $f(P)$ is well defined, i.e., don't depend of how you assign the vertices of polygon. For example, if you take four points $A,B,C,D$ and to consider the polygon $ABCD$ like a square, you have $f\equiv 0$, but if you consider the polygon $ACBD$ this not happen.

Comment: @Walner I do not get what you mean by "$A_2A_3$" isn't an edge. How is it not an edge? The answer has to depend on how you assign the order of the vertices (up to reflection/rotation), since as you said for a square $ABCD$ works but not $ACBD$.

Comment: I want to mean that exist a segment linking $A_2$ to $A_3$. When I say "the polygon $ABCD$" I mean that the only segment that link this vertices are $AB, BC, CD, DA$ and this is a square. While in $ACBD$ the edges is $AC, CB, BD, DA$ and this is like a grail. What I say is that if I re-assign the vertices of such way that you have the same polygon, you have yet $f$ as the same. For example, if I take $CDAB$ instead of $ABCD$, I yet have $f$ as the same, because is the same polygon. But for $ACBD$, $f$ change.

Comment: @Walner The solution, and proof, is independent of the exact values of the variables. You can set them to be anything you want. For example, you can obtain the regular octagon. You can also obtain various other figures.

Comment: Now I know that I can to obtain various other figures. Indeed, other guy showed this for me. But I just want to indicate for you that your example isn't a polygon, even that this pseudo-polygon indeed satisfy $f \equiv 0$. This is the origin of this discussions, isn't? Anyway, I want to thanks your patience. Now is almost 00:00h in here, Brazil, and I must to go sleep. God night!